# Writing 1.5 million rows in a file using Python 3+

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write sql statements into a sql file to create 10,000 tables. Each table containing 5 columns with 1.5 million rows of data in each column.

```
text_file = open("D:\Output.sql", "a", encoding="utf-8")
count = 0
for i in range(1,10001):
    a=[]
    b=[]
    x='Tab_'+str(i)

    a.append(random.choice(name)+'_'+str(i))
    a.append(random.choice(ssn)+'_'+str(i))
    a.append(random.choice(address)+'_'+str(i))
    a.append(random.choice(dob)+'_'+str(i))
    a.append(random.choice(phone)+'_'+str(i))

    text_file.write('create table Python_test.'+ x + '(' +
                    a[0] + ' VARCHAR(255),' + 
                    a[1] +' VARCHAR(255),' + 
                    a[2] +' VARCHAR(255),' + 
                    a[3] +' VARCHAR(255),' + 
                    a[4] +' VARCHAR(255));\n')
    #print('\n')

    for j in range(1,1500001):
        #print(i)
        #print(a)
        text_file.write('insert into '+ x + '('   + 
                         a[0]+','+a[1]+','+a[2]+','+a[3]+','+a[4]+
                        ') values (\''+ 
                        fake.name()+'\',\''+rstr.xeger(random.choice(sList))+'\',\''+
                        fake.address()+'\',\''+rstr.xeger(random.choice(dbList))+'\',\''+
                        rstr.xeger(random.choice(pList))+'\');\n')


    text_file.write('\n')
    count=count+1
    print(count)


text_file.close()
```

The 2 for loops are taking a lot of time. Is there any way to optimize this code to minimalize the amount of time taken to execute this code?

Comment: You can able to create it even though it takes lot of time ? No memory error right ? it looks like its more related to codereview platform than stackoverflow. consider posting it in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah. It's working but taking a huge amount of time. Thanks for the advice. Will do.

Comment: 10,000 tables?!  Woah.

Comment: You do a lot us useless string concatenations. `.write` every piece instead, it could be faster.

Answer (score 0):

A few pieces of advise, not a complete solution.

Do not concatenate strings. Writing to the file will already concatenate them. Consider:

```py
def write_all(f, *pieces):
  for piece in pieces:
    f.write(piece)

# Now you can:

write_all(
  text_file,
  'create table Python_test.', x, '(', 
  a[0], ' VARCHAR(255),',
  # etc ad libitum.
  ');\n'
)
```

In the meantime you can do away with `a[0]`, etc and name things nicely, and also compute `str(i)` only once.

[Open your output file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) as binary (so you don't spent any time on the universal newline conversion or encoding checking), and, most importantly, with a large buffer:

```py
with open("file.sql", "wb", 4000000) as text_ file:
  # Do your generation here
```

Run several processes, for different sub-ranges of `i`, in parallel, writing to different physical devices. I suppose the code is heavily I/O-bound, and mostly waits for writes to complete. Several parallel processes could generate some more data while the previous portion from  different process is consumed by the filesystem; `multiprocessing` module should make it simple.

But don't expect a miracle. You are generating 10k files several MBs each, this is many tens of GBs worth of data. It *will* take some time to just settle on the disk, even the fastest m.2 SSD, especially given the (not very fast) NTFS filesystem.

On a slow disk, it might be useful to pass the output through `gzip`, as it it is generated, so that fewer bytes hit the disk. It should compress pretty well, given the huge amount of common substrings. Then you could unpack the files on the fly while feeding to the database(s) you are testing (because what else could it be?..).

Answer (score -1):

It's usually more efficient to write large files in batches of lines rather than one line at a time. Try building a string of 1000 lines concatenated together (making sure you separate them with `\n`) and then writing the batch to the file before starting the next one.

You can experiment with different batch sizes to get a suitable balance between speed and memory usage.

Comment: The OS does the buffering for you already. Concatenating 1000 lines is expensive, though, it involves a lot of copying in RAM.